# Puppet: Declaring a class with inheritance

Tags: puppet

I currently have two classes that I created within `/etc/puppet/modules/params/manifests/init.pp`

```
class modulename ($variable_name = 'Any string') inherits modulename::params{
  file { '/tmp/mytoplevelclass.sh' :
    mode    => '644',
    ensure  => 'present',
    content => $variable_name
  }
}

class modulename::params{

}
```

However, I am having an issue declaring these classes in `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`. Currently, I have it written as

```
node default { #client
  class { 'modulename':}
  class { 'modulename::params':}
}
```

I know that this is incorrect because when I run `puppet agent -t` on the client I get an error stating

> Could not find declared class modulename at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

I have tried several different configurations and still am unsure on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet determines the file in which it expects to find a class's definition based on the class's fully-qualified name.  The docs go into it in some detail; in particular, you should review the [Module Fundamentals](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/modules_fundamentals.html). (I am guessing that you are on Puppet 3, but the details I am about to discuss are unchanged in Puppet 4.)

Supposing that `/etc/puppet/modules` is a directory in your modulepath, it is a fine place to install (or write) your `modulename` module, as indeed you indicate you are doing.  If it is not in your module path, then you'll want either to move your module to a directory in the module path, or to add that directory to the module path.  I assume that you will resolve any problem of this sort via the latter alternative, so that `/etc/puppet/modules/modulename` is a valid module directory.

Now, class 'modulename' is a bit special in that its name is also a module name; as such, it should be defined in `/etc/puppet/modules/modulename/manifests/init.pp`.  Class `modulename::params`, on the other hand, should follow the normal pattern, being defined in `/etc/puppet/modules/modulename/manifests/params.pp`.  I anticipate that Puppet will find the definitions if you put the definitions in the correct files.

Bonus advice:

- Use [include-like class declarations](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like) in your node blocks, not resource-like declarations
- Your node blocks probably should not declare `modulename::params` at all